# AngularJS cant get information out of object

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with the following problem:

I'm getting a json-response from my backend service which is called from my services.js.
In detail:
(this is the last of many attempts...)

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

var testServices = angular.module('testServices', ['ngResource']);

var eventtracker = {};

...

testServices.factory('TestSvc',
function($rootScope, $http, $timeout) {

  initTest: function(){
      var dataresponse = {};
      dataresponse.events = new Array();
      dataresponse.currentuser = "";
      dataresponse.error = "";

  eventtracker.lasteventindex = 0;

  $http.get('rest/testservice/test/events/0').then(function(r) {
         if (r.data.error === null){
     eventtracker.lasteventindex = r.data.events.length; // == save last event index

     ....
     //doing a lot of stuff here to collect all data to dataresponse object
     ....
     //for example:
         for (var i=0;i<parseInt(eventtracker.lasteventindex);i++)
     {
        for (sKey in r.data.events[i])
           {
            //scan for controller
            if (sKey==="controller"){
            if (i===parseInt(eventtracker.lasteventindex) - 1){
                   //get current user
               dataresponse.currentuser = r.data.events[i][sKey];
                }
            c++;
            dataresponse.events[c] = new Object();
            dataresponse.events[c]["controller"] = r.data.events[i][sKey];
            dataresponse.events[c]["column"] = r.data.events[i][sKey];
            }   
     }
     }

     ....
     //and so on...
  }
  }
  //after all of that, datresponse object will be returned
  return dataresponse; 
  }
 };
}
);
```

so far so good...

Now, when I pass the object into $scope.data and doing a {{data | json}} everything works fine! (Json is valid and output is correct!).

But, if I would like to get some specific information out of the object (from my controller, to pass it to the correct $scope, it doesnt work.)
in detail:

going to controllers.js:

```
testControllers.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'TestSvc',   '$routeParams', '$log', 
function($scope, TestSvc, $routeParams, $log) {
    $scope.data = TestSvc.initTest(); //this is working!!
}
]);
```

Output of $scope.data ({{data | json}}):

```
{
 "events": [
  {
    "controller": "TESTUSER",
    "column": 1
  },
  {
    "controller": "TESTUSER",
    "column": 2
  },
  {
    "controller": "TESTUSER",
    "column": 3
  },
  {
    "controller": "TESTUSER",
    "column": 0
  }
],
"currentuser": "TESTUSER",
"error": ""
}
```

and I'm able to get all the information out of this object on template side like:
    Test1: {{data.events[0].controller | json}}

result is: TESTUSER -> PERFECT!

BUT, as I said, if I would like to get any detailed information out of the object on controller side - I'm not able to do it.

For example:
by doing this in controller function:

```
 $scope.test = $scope.data.currentuser;
```

result: nothing on view level (no error, just nothing)

template:
    {{test}}

or

controller:

```
$scope.test = $scope.data.events[0].controller;
```

result: On view side, now angular stops working completely - but again no error.
In that case, the result on view side is {{test}} and also everything else isn't parsed now.

only by passing the complete object to $scope.test its working:

```
$scope.test = $scope.data //-> works! (output is json like above)
```

I also tried to get more information about the object on controller side, for example:

```
$scope.data.events.length
```

it returns 0 -> always 0...

I really don't get it...

Of course I tried a lot more of attempts like:

```
$scope.test = $scope.data.events[0]["controller"]; -> angular "stops" working
$scope.test = $scope.data[0]; -> nothing happens
$scope.test = $scope.data[0]["currentuser"]; -> angular "stops" working
```

and and and....

Why is this not working on controllers side but it is working on view side and services side?!?!

I'm just able to parse the whole object threw the controller, but I'm not able to get any information out of it....
I'm sure I have just overseen something - unfortunately I don't know what...

Thanks a lot guys and kr,
Martin

Comment: You need to learn to formulate a question properly. As it is now, its too much text saying too nothing. get to the point

Comment: Well, thanks for the advice RedHotScalability - I'll do my best next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your service `TestSvc` for the data, the service is returning the result of the `$http` call.  However, this code is async.  The `$http` call calls the callback (i.e. `.then(function(r) {}`) when the server call completes.

So, you are getting into a situation where your response to the service call is still empty when you return it.

It is better practice, to return the promise from the service:

```
return $http.get('rest/testservice/test/events/0');
```

And then handle the promise in the controller:

```
TestSvc.initTest().then(function(data) { ... });
```

Promises can be chained.  So, you can keep all the logic in the service if you want, but you would need to return another promise that is the result of the logic inside the service.

[More about promises and $q here in the docs.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Comment: Thanks Davin, that was the solution!